# iPhone 5 not downloading apps from App Store

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

My iphone 5 is not downloadig any apps from the App Store.  I reset all settings, reset all network settings, changed WiFi DNS, set date and time, reset my phone, and tried to download on WiFi, LTE and 3G but faced same problem.

Comment: What version of iOS is on your phone? Perhaps your problem has something to do with your iTunes account or Apple ID, you can try logging out and back in in settings.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your iOS on iPhone setting. Hope this work for you!